# Change orientation in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, paintcomponent

I am writing a simple application that draws the NYC subway map. I have succeeded in doing so and my maps prints in JFrame object. However, it prints on the wrong side because I assume it references the 0 0 point on the top left corner. How can I make it reference the bottom left corner so it will print the right way?

```
private final List<Shape> shapes;
private double maxLat = 40.903125;
private double maxLon = -73.755405;
private double minLat = 40.512764;
private double minLon = -74.251961;
private final double latLength;
private final double lonLength;

public Shapes() throws IOException {
    this.shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();

    CSVReader in = new CSVReader(new FileReader(
            "src/charnetskaya/subwaymap/shapes.txt"));
    String[] line;
    in.readNext();
    while ((line = in.readNext()) != null) {
        double lat = Double.valueOf(line[1]);
        double lon = Double.valueOf(line[2]);
        Shape shape = new Shape(line[0], lat, lon);
        shapes.add(shape);

        this.maxLat = Math.max(this.maxLat, shape.getLat());
        this.maxLon = Math.max(this.maxLon, shape.getLon());
        this.minLat = Math.min(this.minLat, shape.getLat());
        this.minLon = Math.min(this.minLon, shape.getLon());
    }

    this.latLength = Math.abs(this.maxLat - this.minLat);
    this.lonLength = Math.abs(this.maxLon - this.minLon);
    System.out.println(latLength + " " + lonLength);

}
```

graphics method

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics pen) {
    System.out.println("Tring to draw");
    Graphics2D pen2D = (Graphics2D) pen;
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    System.out.println(width + " | " + height);

    double minLat = this.shapes.getMinLat();
    double minLon = this.shapes.getMinLon();
    double latLength = this.shapes.getLatLength();
    double lonLength = this.shapes.getLonLength();
    List<String> shapeIds = this.shapes.getShapeIds();
    for (String shapeId : shapeIds) {

        List<Shape> list = this.shapes.getShapes(shapeId);

        Trip trip = this.trips.getTrip(shapeId);
        if (trip != null) {
            Color color = this.routes.getColor(trip.getRouteId());
            pen2D.setColor(color);
            for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
                Shape a = list.get(i - 1);
                Shape b = list.get(i);
                int x1 = (int) ((a.getLat() - minLat) / latLength * height);
                int y1 = (int) ((a.getLon() - minLon) / lonLength * height);
                int x2 = (int) ((b.getLat() - minLat) / latLength * height);
                int y2 = (int) ((b.getLon() - minLon) / lonLength * height);

                // if ((x1 != x2) || (y1 != y2)) {
                pen2D.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
                // }
            }
        }

    }
```

[image: Picture of my disaster] [image: NYC subway map]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
int x1 = (int) ((a.getLat() - minLat) / latLength * height);
int y1 = (int) ((a.getLon() - minLon) / lonLength * height);
```

to

```
int x1 = (int) ((a.getLon() - minLon) / lonLength * width);
int y1 = (int) ((maxLat - a.getlat()) / latLength * height);
```

and similarly for `x2` and `y2`.

Comment: int x1 = (int) ((a.getLon() - minLon) / lonLength * width);
int y1 = (int) (maxLat - (a.getLat()) / latLength * height);
int x2 = (int) ((b.getLon() - minLon) / lonLength * width);
int y2 = (int) ((maxLat - b.getLat()) / latLength * height);

Comment: No, not like what you typed.  You have put parentheses in different places from where I had them, in the expression for `y1`.

Comment: thanx for your helf, but maybe you can help me also to turn north to the top left corner, the way this subway map is naturaly is

Comment: So, which way do you want it to point?  What angle?  Sorry, I'm not from New York and I've never seen this map before.

Comment: Oh, is that grey pacman-shaped thing in the Long Island Sound supposed to be a north-pointing arrow?

Comment: i added 2 more images, num 3 is the way it looks now, and num 4 is the way it suppose to look, it should be a little off north

Comment: OK, I understand, and I do know how to do this.  But there will be a bit of backwards and forwards and tweaking parameters to get it to look just right.  It's probably easiest for us to talk through it, rather than taking turns commenting here.  Unfortunately, I don't have time right now.  Will you be available to talk this through, in about 10 hours or so?

Comment: yeah definitely, thanx so much...just post here

Comment: oh i am sorry, i thought u meant to discuss here whenever either of us comes with reply. I see we are in a major time difference. my time is +5 what is yours?

Comment: No problem.  I could just post a whole lot of code, but it wouldn't quite work, because there would be some constants that control the scaling and the amount of rotation.  I would need to show you how to tweak those constants to make everything work right, and I'm not sure how to do that in just a single posting.  I also don't know how much I need to explain, because I don't know how comfortable you are with trigonometry.  I will have some time tomorrow to help you with this, if you're online.  Alternatively, you could ask another question, and somebody else might be able to help you.